# LibXML2 date validation errors with regular expression

Tags: php, schema, libxml2, xml-validation

I have a problem while validating XML against schema that uses regular expression. I'm using LibXML. Actually the libXML is used by PHP, but same problem, of course, occurs in the console. XML should be valid since I tested it with some online validators.

Anyway workarounds? Modifying the schema is not a very good option because it's provided by a third party source.

I'm using xmllint command with libXML versions 2.7.8 and 2.9.1.

```
xmllint: using libxml version 20708
   compiled with: Threads Tree Output Push Reader Patterns Writer SAXv1 FTP HTTP DTDValid HTML Legacy C14N Catalog XPath XPointer XInclude Iconv ISO8859X Unicode Regexps Automata Expr Schemas Schematron Modules Debug Zlib

xmllint: using libxml version 20901
   compiled with: Threads Tree Output Push Reader Patterns Writer SAXv1 FTP HTTP DTDValid HTML Legacy C14N Catalog XPath XPointer XInclude Iconv ISO8859X Unicode Regexps Automata Expr Schemas Schematron Modules Debug Zlib
```

**Command I use:**

```
 xmllint --noout -schema s x
```

**Errors I get:**

```
x:2: element testdate: Schemas validity error : Element 'testdate': [facet 'pattern'] The value '31.8.2013' is not accepted by the pattern '((([0-2]{0,1}[0-9]{1})|(3[0,1]{1}))\.((0?[1-9]{1})|(1[0-2]{1}))\.2[0-9]{3})?'.
x:2: element testdate: Schemas validity error : Element 'testdate': '31.8.2013' is not a valid value of the atomic type 'mdatetype'.
x fails to validate
```

**My XML file named 'x' is:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testdate>31.8.2013</testdate>
```

**My schema named 's' is:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="testdate" type="mdatetype"/>
    <xs:simpleType name="mdatetype">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="10"/>
            <xs:pattern value="((([0-2]{0,1}[0-9]{1})|(3[0,1]{1}))\.((0?[1-9]{1})|(1[0-2]{1}))\.2[0-9]{3})?"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

**Edit**

Some regular expressions work. I tested with finnish sosial security numbers

**Schema**

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <xs:element name="x" />
        <xs:element name="testdate" type="mdatetype" />
        <xs:element name="testhetu" type="mhetu" />
        <xs:simpleType name="mdatetype">
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:pattern value="((([0-2]{0,1}[0-9]{1})|(3[0,1]{1}))\.((0?[1-9]{1})|(1[0-2]{1}))\.2[0-9]{3})?"/>
                </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
        <xs:simpleType name="mhetu">
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:pattern value="((([0-2]{1}[0-9]{1})|(3[0,1]{1}))((0[0-9]{1})|(1[0-2]{1}))[0-9]{2}[\+\-aA]{1}[0-9]{3}[0-9A-Fa-fHhJ-Nj-nPpR-Yr-y]{1})?"/>
                </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

**XML**

```
<x>
<testhetu>151182-152x</testhetu>
<testhetu>151182A154G</testhetu>
</x>
```

**Result (only the latest SSN is invalid, since G is not allowed) **

```
x:3: element testhetu: Schemas validity error : Element 'testhetu': [facet 'pattern'] The value '151182A154G' is not accepted by the pattern '((([0-2]{1}[0-9]{1})|(3[0,1]{1}))((0[0-9]{1})|(1[0-2]{1}))[0-9]{2}[\+\-aA]{1}[0-9]{3}[0-9A-Fa-fHhJ-Nj-nPpR-Yr-y]{1})?'.
x:3: element testhetu: Schemas validity error : Element 'testhetu': '151182A154G' is not a valid value of the atomic type 'mhetu'.
x fails to validate
```

Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like libxml doesn't understand your notation of 0 to 1 in repetition count, which can simply be replaced with a questionmark.

So your pattern in the first schema should be:

```
((([0-2]?[0-9]{1})|(3[0,1]{1}))\.((0?[1-9]{1})|(1[0-2]{1}))\.2[0-9]{3})?
```

Or better yet you can simplify it down to:

```
((([0-2]?[0-9])|(3[0,1]))\.((0?[1-9])|(1[0-2]))\.2[0-9]{3})?
```

This is because you don't need to explicitly say that this character repeats 1 time since repeating once is the default.

Comment: Thats true, but changing the schema in this situation is not a good idea. But i'll do that until find an another solution. Those were just minimalized example schemas. Is there a bug in libxml?